# Issue with *some* UIViews needing width and height backward in their frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a game on the iPhone, however I am running in to some (I hope) simple, yet confusing issues.

I am forcing my application to be in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight mode, this is set in the .plist and each of my UIViewControllers returns this as the only viable orientation for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

That works... sometimes. Each of my xibs have been designed to be in landscape mode, and all ViewControllers are set up in a very similar fashion. Here is my problem:

I instantiate all of my UIViewControllers programatically such as:

```
splashScreen = [[SplashScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
splashScreen.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[GameConsts defaultGameConsts] screenWidth], [[GameConsts defaultGameConsts] screenHeight]);
[[self view] addSubview: [splashScreen view]];
```

mainMenu = [[MainMenuController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 mainMenu.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[GameConsts defaultGameConsts] screenWidth], [[GameConsts defaultGameConsts] screenHeight]);
 [[self view] addSubview: [mainMenu view]];

This works fine, but when I activate my "game views", i.e., the in-game menus and actual playing field I need to invert the screenWidth and screenHeight parameters to get them to be correctly displayed. I do not understand why this is, and I have not yet been able to figure it out. Here is how they are being instantiated:

```
- (void) setupGameViews
{
 // Why do these need to be reversed to show up properly? (Height and Width!)
 gameView = [[GameController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 gameView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[GameConsts defaultGameConsts] screenHeight], [[GameConsts defaultGameConsts] screenWidth]);
 [[self view] addSubview: [gameView view]];

 gameMenu = [[GameMenuController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameMenuView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 gameMenu.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[GameConsts defaultGameConsts] screenHeight], [[GameConsts defaultGameConsts] screenWidth]);
 [[self view] addSubview: [gameMenu view]];
}
```

(Note: This method is being called when a start game button is clicked. This is all inside a "parent" UIViewController that has no associated view with it, but instead contains and sets up all of these subviews. Maybe there is an issue with their architecture? I have seen some similar examples around, so I decided to use it.)

For completeness, here are the definitions in the GameConsts singleton during its init method:

```
- (id) init
{
 screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width;
 screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height;

 screenCenter = CGPointMake(screenSizeHeight / 2, screenSizeWidth / 2);

 return [super init];
}
```

screenWidth and screenHeight are floats. screenCenter is a CGPoint. If you note, I have reversed the height/width in the screenCenter CGPoint because otherwise when I try to draw an object at the screen center it shows up in the bottom left corner of the screen.

This is driving me crazy and keeping me from the far more fun parts of this experience. If anyone can provide help, it would be wonderful. If any more information is needed, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `applicationFrame` always returns a frame for portrait orientation.

Comment: That would make a ton of sense, and I'd feel quite silly that being the case. (And it certainly jives with what I've seen elsewhere). My only question in that case is: Why does it work with the first two Views? splashScreen and mainMenu?

Comment: I just tried switching the width/height for the views that work the way you'd think they should - the aforementioned splashScreen and mainMenu. They get skewed pretty badly. One ends up being larger than the screen, and pushed upward a little bit (splashScreen), the other ends up on the top side of the screen (mainMenu). One becomes larger than the viewable area and the other only takes up half of it, as if the views weren't rotating properly (the label is in the correct place, but the view doesn't cover the whole area). Neither of these makes sense to me...

Comment: Is GameConsts giving the screen width/height directly from [UIScreen applicationFrame]?

Comment: Another gotcha is that I believe your root view controller's frame is _always_ in portrait mode.  UIViewController sets itself to landscape by applying a 90 degree rotation to its transform if it's the root controller (highest in the view hierarchy).

Comment: Are you asking whether it is re-accessed? No - once the GameConsts is initialized, the screenWidth and screenHeight will remain whatever the applicationFrame was when the GameConsts singleton was initially accessed. (I apologize for the edits, I keep hitting enter trying to make paragraphs)

Comment: Another thing to try: after your view hierarchy is set up, do NSLog(@"%@", [window recursiveDescription]); in your app delegate.  You can use performSelector:withObject:nil afterDelay: if needed to make the call after the views are set up.  recursiveDescription is an undocumented method that returns a nice big string summarizing your entire view hierarchy, including all frames.  Very handy for debugging.

Comment: The root UIViewController (the one that all these subviews are being created in) does override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and only returns true for UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. Is that what you mean? It is the only other view controller I'm aware of and it's the one started by the delegate. There may be a root one that is behind the scenes, though, and if so - is this what you mean? If this is my issue, how would I best handle such a thing?

Comment: You're right that the parent view is in portrait mode, it has a frame of (0 0; 320 480) whereas all of the ones I have created have a frame of (0 0; 480 320). This still doesn't explain why I can handle (screenWidth,screenHeight) to some and (screenHeight,screenWidth) to others and get the same dimensions. Is there a proper way to change the parent view, or is that moot and useless?

Comment: You shouldn't have to mess with the parent's coordinates - it's definitely cleaner and considered more correct to avoid that.  I really suggest using NSLog statements with the output of recursiveDescription to explore all the frames.  Your frames should be what you set them to, but keep in mind that the bounds and transform (other UIViewController properties) might be different. If you can narrow down the discrepancy between what works and what doesn't, you'll have the answer. These comments have exhausted my ideas for now.  Btw, just in case it's useful, press cmd-shift-R to see NSLog output.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions. I'll look more into the recursiveDescription tomorrow after some rest, but that's where I got the frame sizes for the parent/my views in the previous comment. There's definitely something weird going on with this, and I truly don't know what it is. If something hits you and you think of a possible explanation, please do tell. Maybe I'm just doing things in a bad way - does it look overly complicated or outrageous? Should I be avoiding a parent UIViewController that manages some subviews including the game's view?

Comment: I've added some logging to try to figure out what's going on here, and I'm still in the dark. I logged when GameConsts initializes, and it only happens once (as expected). Each time one of either screenWidth or screenHeight is accessed it returns the value you would expect (320 for width, 480 for height). -- What this means is that it appears you had the correct idea and I indeed have these backward due to your answer, but that begets the question.. why are the first two view controllers backward? If you think of an answer to that, or something to pursue, let me know! Thank you for the help!